# Mapping Types From C to Java In JNA

Tags: java, c, types, jna

I am trying to map a function in a C library to a java project using JNA. The C function is this:

```c
int foobar(const int a, u8* b);
```

What are the correct types to use?

Is this correct?

```java
int foobar(int a, int b);
```

Answer (score 0):

C's `int` maps to `int` in JNA, but `u8` is an 8-bit unsigned integer (a `byte`), plus the `*` means it's a pointer.

The natural interpretation is a `ByteByReference` where JNA would allocate a byte and return a pointer to it that you would pass to the function.  You'd use `getValue()` on the `ByteByReference` to extract the returned byte.

However, there may be other reasons to pass a pointer to a byte. Here is where you'll need the API to document what that second parameter does.

Note also that the `u` is "unsigned" so the returned value will have a native meaning of 0 to 255, while Java only uses unsigned bytes and you'll get a value from -128 to 127. You'll have to convert.